# Disable page scroll when positioned over an element?

Tags: jquery, css

Lets say I have a popup on my page, with a y-scrollbar, like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

As normal, if I was to hover over the list I can use the mousewheel to scroll up or down.  When I reach the bottom of the list, the mousewheel then causes the whole page to scroll down.

Is there a method to allow scrolling in the popup, but prevent the page from scrolling when the pointer is positioned on top of the popup?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `overflow` css property of the page to `overflow-y:hidden` when mouse is over the popup.

For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/YNZuk/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.popup').on('mouseover',function(){$('body').css('overflow-y','hidden');});
    $('.popup').on('mouseout',function(){$('body').css('overflow-y','auto');});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis.....a lot of data...
<div class="popup">
        <b>this is a popup</b><br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam.Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia,..
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup{
        background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you've tagged Jquery and Css so my Advice is that you give `body,html` `overflow:hidden;` when you open the PopUp using Jquery, 
and you make it `overflow:auto;` when popup is closed. 
something like this for instance:

```
    $('#YourElement').click(function{
    //show popup
    //hide overflow
$('body,html').css('overflow','hidden');
    });
```

and something similar on close